# When braking and the car is near to stop I hear the sound of acceleration

Tags: braking

Sometimes when I brake and the car is `near to stop`, I hear the sound of acceleration from the engine, i.e., it is like if I would have pressed the gas pedal (but I didn't do it). This happens randomly, any idea what causes this problem?
This happens randomly in both cases (1) when I press clutch+brake simultaneously or (2) brake alone.

```
Model:  Dacia Logan (Renault)
Transmission type: Manual Transmission
```

Comment: I'm wondering if your foot is inadvertently catching the gas pedal while braking. This can happen to the best of us, especially if the pedals are close together. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm sure, my foot isn't catching the gas pedal. For several years I have had the same car. Only recently (since few weeks) I have had this problem.

Comment: Have you noticed any change in throttle response, acceleration, or idle speed? I'm thinking the MAF sensor or throttle plate could be dirty, causing strange idle conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I have a manual Subaru with electronic throttle control and this happens to me sometimes. The ECU is assuming that you are about to downshift, ie, into a parking lot or something similar. It increases revs to make the downshift smoother. Most of the time it does this when you want it to and you don't notice, but sometimes it guesses wrong.

More info is at this forum post:

http://forums.nasioc.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2014438

Comment: This is what I was thinking. My '06 Corolla does the same sometimes, and I've never noticed anything abnormal from it.